# Selecting the same item from a vba range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]The code below copies values from another workbook. However, instead of copying values exactly the way they appear in the source workbook, I want it to copy items of the same kind (all of them), insert a blank row, and copy another of the same kind. Example attached.

```vb
    Sub NewWBandPasteSpecialALLSheets()
       Dim wb As Workbook
       Dim wbNew As Workbook
       Dim sh As Worksheet
       Dim shNew As Worksheet
    
       Set wb = ThisWorkbook
       Workbooks.Add                
       Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    
       On Error Resume Next
    
       For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
          sh.Range("C1:C180, D1:D180,E1:E180, F1:F180, G1:G180").Copy ' I want this range to copy groups of items that are the same and insert a row.
    
          With wbNew.Worksheets
    
              Set shNew = Nothing
              Set shNew = .Item(sh.Name)
    
              If shNew Is Nothing Then
                  .Add After:=.Item(.Count)
                  .Item(.Count).Name = sh.Name
                  Set shNew = .Item(.Count)
              End If
               End With
    
    
          With shNew.Range("A1")
              .PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)
              .PasteSpecial (xlValues)
          End With
       Next
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Duplicated Rows to a New Workbook

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewWBandPasteSpecialALLSheets()
       
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long, sr As Long
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dData As Variant
    Dim drCount As Long, dr As Long, dn As Long
    
    Dim cCount As Long, c As Long
    Dim FirstDone As Boolean
    
    For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
        
        Set srg = sws.Range("C1:G180")
        
        If Not FirstDone Then
            srCount = srg.Rows.Count
            drCount = 2 * srCount
            cCount = srg.Columns.Count
        End If
        
        sData = srg.Value
        
        ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
        dr = 0
        
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            For dn = 1 To 2
                dr = dr + 1
                For c = 1 To cCount
                    dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
                Next c
            Next dn
        Next sr
        
        If FirstDone Then
           Set dws = dwb.Worksheets.Add(After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count))
        Else
           Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
           FirstDone = True
        End If
        
        dws.Name = sws.Name
          
        With dws.Range("A1")
            .Resize(drCount, cCount).Value = dData
            srg.Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            Application.Goto .Cells, True
        End With
    
    Next sws
    
    Application.Goto dwb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing the previous code was doing.

Comment: Maybe you're accidentally running your code, they have the same name. Feel free to [download my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9DGWampdD1TN1f5scymhXq-omHV95Ca/view?usp=sharing) from Google Drive.

Comment: Firstly I will like to thank you for you effort. I have limited skill on VBA, hence, I am practically struggling at this point. Notwithstanding, I discovered that your data has only column header, no row. What I wanted was for the code to collect all the duplicate values from C1:C180, insert a blank row at the end of each collected duplicate values.

Comment: E.g collect all the Beat FM in that range, insert a blank row, collect all the Wazobia FM, and insert a blank row. Collect all these with corresponding values in other ranges (in range D1:D180,E1:E180, F1:F180, G1:G180)

Comment: It's still not entirely clear. Could you post a screenshot of the desired result with column (`A,B,C`) and row (`1,2,3`) headers? Also, in which column is `BEATFM LAGOS`?

Comment: 1. Screenshot of desired outcome attached. My dataset has the same columns as above. I want the duplicate to be categorized. For instance, if there are 50 BEAT FMs in C:C I  want all of them to be copied along with their time, date, program (evening in that row. As shown above). After all the BEAT FM has been copied, insert a blank row and copy the next duplicate station.

Comment: I wnat to copy identical values together.